# MatLab to Python conversion - indexing?

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to convert the following MatLab code to Python:

```
    for i = 1:n
     I = (sum((N==M(1,i))+(N==M(2,i)))==2);
     P(:,i) = pit(:,I);
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
 for i in range(0,n):
     I = [sum(int(N == M)(1,i)) + int((int(N == M)(2,i))) == 2]
```

which raises the error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

The following Python code that I have already translated (correctly, I think) precedes the code I am struggling with:

```
 M = np.array(mypitches).transpose()

 n = M.size

 P = np.zeros((3,n))


 pit = pitches(h,-8,12)



 N = np.array(['Fb','Cb','Gb','Db','Ab','Eb','Bb','F-','C-','G-','D-','A-','E-','B-','F#','C#','G#','D#','A#','E#','B#']).transpose()
```

**Full MatLab code:**

```
function [P] = position(h,mypitches);

% position.m : gives pitch positions given
%        h = aspect ratio
%        mypitches = a list of pitch names from Fb-B#
% returns
%        P = a list of corresponding pc spiral positions
%
% created by EC, 20 Nov 1998; updated 28 Aug 2013
%
% usage:     [P] = position(mypitches)
% example: position(['Bb';'C-']);

M = mypitches';
[m,n] = size(M);

P = zeros(3,n);
pit = pitches2(h,-8,12);

N = ['Fb';'Cb';'Gb';'Db';'Ab';'Eb';'Bb';'F-';'C-';'G-';'D-';'A-';'E-';'B-';'F#';'C#';'G#';'D#';'A#';'E#';'B#']';

for i = 1:n
 I = (sum((N==M(1,i))+(N==M(2,i)))==2);
 P(:,i) = pit(:,I);
end;
```

Comment: The loop doesn't work like that. Look into `range`

Comment: Once you've written something, run it and attempt to fix the errors

Comment: Pure guesswork like this won't get you very far

Comment: "Pure guesswork" is going a little far. I am asking specific questions about small parts to resolve the problem.

Comment: What are `M` and `N` in Matlab? How about Python?

Comment: Thanks. Actually they are assigned earlier, will update post:

Comment: What's the shape of `M` in both languages?

Comment: FYI, `x.size` in Python is `numel(x)` in Matlab, and `size(x)` in Matlab is `x.shape` in Python.

Comment: If I understand M is [1, lengthof'mypitches']

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do this. The ndarray indexing is wrong.

```
for i in range(n):
    I = (sum(int(N == M[0, i]) + int(N == M[1, i])) == 2)
    P[:, i] = pit[:, I]
```

It could be written a little more clearer as

```
for i in range(n):
    I = (N == M[0, i] == M[1, i])   # True is equivalent to 1 and False 0
    P[:, i] = pit[:, I]
```

Comment: this line: I = (N == M[1, i] == M[2, i])   # True is equivalent to 1 and False 0 gives me the following error:

IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Maybe I didn't translate the code before properly. This is the MatLab code before:
M = mypitches';
[m,n] = size(M);

P = zeros(3,n);
pit = pitches2(h,-8,12);

N = ['Fb';'Cb';'Gb';'Db';'Ab';'Eb';'Bb';'F-';'C-';'G-';'D-';'A-';'E-';'B-';'F#';'C#';'G#';'D#';'A#';'E#';'B#']';

Comment: What is mypitches? It would be helpful if you give the complete working Matlab code.

Comment: Added to bottom of post.

Comment: @syntheso Uhmm.. you have a function pitches2 in your code. Doesn't look like a MATLAB built-in. What is it's I/O ?

Comment: It returns a 3 x (b-a+1) matrix of pitch positions

Comment: @syntheso what inputs are you giving to your python code. Is the no. of rows in M always 2 ? because it seems you are only using the first 2 rows. I also made an indexing mistake. In python indexing starts from 0. I have edited above answer.

Comment: after importing math: aspect_ratio = sqrt(2/15)
position(aspect_ratio,['Bb', 'C-'])

Comment: ['Bb', 'C-'] is the recommended input, but I think it is meant to be of any length.